# ¿Cómo cambiar el icono de un item dinamicamente?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

Deseo cambiar dinámicamente el icono del item que este selecionado en ese momento pero no puedo accesar a la propiedad icon de los item. para que de esa manera sea mas visible el lugar del menu en el cual se encuentra en el momento. He intentado usar la opción setIcon del item pero el IDE no me da esa propiedad y no a que se deba, solo muestra la propiedad icon pero no se como usarla.

```
override fun onNavigated(controller: NavController, destination: NavDestination) {
    //mapViewModel.showingMap.postValue(destination.id == R.id.navigation_home)
    Home = findViewById<View>(R.id.navigation_home)
    Orders = findViewById<View>(R.id.navigation_history)
    Mesages = findViewById<View>(R.id.navigation_messages)

    when (destination.id) {
        R.id.navigation_home -> {
            //footer_container.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            //putFragmentOn(OrderPickerFragment.newInstance(), footer_container.id)


            //Tab tab = newTab().setIcon(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), icon)));
            Home!!.icon
        }
        R.id.navigation_history -> {
            removeFragmentFrom(footer_container.id)
            footer_container.visibility = View.GONE
        }
        R.id.navigation_messages -> {
            removeFragmentFrom(footer_container.id)
            footer_container.visibility = View.GONE
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/group_3449"
        android:iconTint="@drawable/group_3459"
        android:title="@string/title_home" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_history"
        android:icon="@drawable/group_3455"
        android:title="@string/title_history" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_messages"
        android:icon="@drawable/group_3460"
        android:title="@string/mensajes" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sin temor a equivocarme, estas buscando un efecto que ya lo hace un NavigationView. Por que no pruebas con este ejemplo

```
 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
android:id="@+id/nav_view"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="start"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
app:itemIconTint="#000000"
app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

aqui hay mas información:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView

Answer (score 0):

Esta seria una forma de realizarlo dinamicamente, solo es cuestión de jugar con el MenuItem

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_grid:
                if(isLinear) {
                    item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_list_black_24dp);
                    this.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));
                    isLinear = !isLinear;
                } else {
                    item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_grid_on_black_24dp);
                    this.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
                    isLinear = !isLinear;
                }
                return true;
            case R.id.action_settings:
                Toast.makeText(this, "action_settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```